# MongoDB - find query taking a lot of time

Tags: mongodb

Here is what **db.mycoll.find({MY_FIELD:"FALSE"}).explain()** returns -

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor MY_FIELD_1",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 843392,
"nscannedObjects" : 843392,
"nscanned" : 843392,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 843392,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 843392,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 17798,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 636733,
"indexBounds" : {
    "MY_FIELD" : [
        [
            "FALSE",
            "FALSE"
        ]
    ]
},
"server" : "db-2:30000",
"filterSet" : false
```

And here is what **db.mycoll.stats()** returns -

```
"ns" : "810.mycoll",
"count" : 1052404,
"size" : 4052704096,
"avgObjSize" : 3850,
"storageSize" : 4841168896,
"numExtents" : 24,
"nindexes" : 5,
"lastExtentSize" : 1257897984,
"paddingFactor" : 1,
"systemFlags" : 1,
"userFlags" : 1,
"totalIndexSize" : 215903632,
"indexSizes" : {
    "_id_" : 38484432,
    "fieldA_1" : 42155456,
    "fieldB_1_MY_FIELD_1" : 54255936,
    "fieldC_1" : 42343504,
    "MY_FIELD_1" : 38664304
},
"ok" : 1
```

My Quesns are -

1. Why is it taking 10 mins (636 secs) even when I have an index on MY_FIELD?
2. How do I fix this? Is there anyway **find** takes lesser time?

Stuff that I know -

1. There is no contention (read/write) for this database. It has a total of around 1 million docs.
2. MY_FIELD has only two possible values

Here is **mongostat** data

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults  locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time 
    *0      7    436     *0       0     7|0       0   304g   610g  2.12g     40   810:5.6%          0       0|0     3|1   257k   521k    21   20:39:35 
    *0      1    179     *0       0     3|0       0   304g   610g  2.12g     11   810:0.0%          0       0|0     1|1    99k   520k    21   20:39:36 
    *0     *0     53     *0       0     3|0       0   304g   610g  2.12g      3  1273:8.7%          0       1|0     1|1    28k     1m    22   20:39:37 
    *0     *0    805     *0       0     2|0       0   304g   610g  2.12g     44   810:0.0%          0       1|1     2|1   440k   519k    21   20:39:39 
    *0   2966    112     *0       0     1|0       0   304g   610g  2.12g     12   810:2.6%          0       0|0     1|1    63k   518k    21   20:39:40 
    *0      1    398     *0       0     1|0       0   304g   610g  2.12g      9   810:0.0%          0       1|0     1|1   238k   520k    21   20:39:41 
    *0     *0    987     *0       0     1|0       0   304g   610g  2.13g    101   810:0.0%          0       1|2     2|1   612k   518k    21   20:39:42 
    *0     11     86     *0       0    10|0       0   304g   610g  2.13g     17
```

Comment: The index is working perfectly, but you're returning over 800,000 documents (4/5 of your database) in one query. It's likely the limiting factor is disk I/O to read documents off disk into memory, plus the find yielded a lot to other operations. Incidentally, you have `MY_FIELD` stored as a string, not a boolean, though you intend for it to be a boolean field. Try looking at mongostat while running the query and seeing if there are a lot of page faults.

Comment: really helps.. will try mongostat.. also will use limit and skip.. will get back with the results..

Comment: @wdberkeley .. attached mongostat .. this looks like a lot of page faults.. because generally i see 0 for other databases which are small.. do you think skip and limit should help me?...i saw that putting a limit of 100 brings down query time by "10000" times

Comment: Reducing the number of results you return will definitely help - but why are you trying to return 4/5 of the database with one query in the first place?

Comment: I have to process and modify each document in this collection and put the modified one in another collection.. I have to do this once per day..

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that though the query is using the index, it takes time to build the documents. `explain` is showing `"indexOnly" : false` which means the index is not a covering index (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain).

You can try this. If you change your query to:

```
db.mycoll.find( {MY_FIELD: "FALSE"}, {_id: 0, MY_FIELD: 1} ).explain()
```

then the index on `MY_FIELD` itself can be used to construct your results. Check if this is running much faster. Obviously this query may not be of much use to you, since this does not return you the documents. This is just to figure out if the time is spent in constructing the documents and not for the search itself.

Also, if `MY_FIELD` is only going to have two values, you are better off using Boolean than string. The document size and index will be smaller.

Comment: This is just to figure out if the time is spent in constructing the documents and not for the search itself >> did help.. i m using skip and limit now..